# Get template variable in onCreated in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am rendering a template with `Blaze.renderWithData(Template.templateName, { key: value })`;

I can get the value in my template with `{{key}}`, but I cannot get the value in my js code.

I have tried

```
Template.templateName.onCreated( () => {
  console.log(Template.instance().key);
});
```

but the variable is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried using the onRendered callback instead of onCreated?http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated: "Callbacks added with this method are called before your template's logic is evaluated for the first time. Inside a callback, this is the new template instance object. Properties you set on this object will be visible from the callbacks added with onRendered and onDestroyed methods and from event handlers."

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
this.data.key
```

or

```
Template.instance().data.key
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
Template.instance().data['your-key']
```

If you have doubt about what is the value, put the break on the source code of the `chrome developer tools` or `firebug` and try to debug. This is the client side, thus all the code will be available

Answer (score 0):

Data passed to template is available on `this` in onCreated function,
so this should works:

```
 Template.templateName.onCreated( () => {
      console.log(this.key);
 });
```

Comment: It is not working. As far as I know, `this` is the same as `Template.instance()`. I have also tried using your approach with a non-anonymous function `Template.templateName.onCreated( function () {` instead of `Template.templateName.onCreated( () => {`. But nothing works.

Comment: It should be this.data.key